# Laravel form submit only selected data assign to Model

Tags: php, laravel

How can i save only selected data to my database table something like this

```
// save weekdays
        $weekdays = new TrainingDay();
        $weekdays->insert($request->weekdays->toArray());
        $weekdays->save();
```

the table only have `id, plan_id, weekday, created_at, updated_at` should i use some array_pluck or something?

---

My sample form submit data

```
  #attributes: array:5 [
    "id" => "1"
    "plan_id" => "1"
    "weekday" => "Trænings dag"
    "created_at" => "2018-08-29 17:42:30"
    "updated_at" => "2018-08-29 17:42:30"
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$weekdays = new TrainingDay();
$weekdays->insert($request->except(['created_at', 'updated_at']));
$weekdays->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `only` method as well.

```
$weekdays = new TrainingDay();
$weekdays->insert($request->only(['id', 'plan_id', 'weekday']));
$weekdays->save();
```